# iOS Xamarin MVVM Light - GetAndRemoveParameter() method

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

I'm a newbie. I pass a parameter from a UIViewController to another with this method:

**FirstViewController:**

```
string parameter = "test";
var navigation = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
navigation.NavigateTo("SecondViewController", parameter);
```

And after I would like to get my parameter:

**SecondViewController:**

```
var nav = new NavigationService().Initialize(NavigationController);
UIViewController controller = nav.NavigationController.TopViewController ; //The UIKit.UIViewController that was navigated to
string param = (String)nav.GetAndRemoveParameter(controller);
```

But the parameter result is null. Where I make mistakes? How can I get my parameter?

Comment: Well lot's of reasons why this is not working. Did you register NavigationService in IoC container for example? You should always use the same instance to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I just registered the NavigationService in IoC container. Maybe..Do I have to use a different controller?

Comment: I resolved, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error in this way:

```
var navigation = (NavigationService)ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
```

I must to use a cast before this line of code.
**Thank you all**